# Meaning of regularity of a domain?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the meaning of regularity of an open domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Please explain. I have google it but find nothing fruitful. If possible, please provide some examples also.

Comment: I don't think it has a standard meaning.  Usually it means some kind of smoothness on the boundary.  For example, it might be that the boundary is piecewise the graph of a $C^\infty$, $C^1$, or Lipschitz function.

Comment: For example any domain with smooth boundary. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: Thank you very much.